# Wrong time saved in DB rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have Orders in my DB where `created_at` is very important.

When a new order is created by a client and hence saved to the database, the `created_at` is one hour ahead, e.g. if an order is created at 3:00 the `created_at`in the DB will be 2:00.

I actually configured my `application.rb` in order to solve the issue:

```
# timezone
config.time_zone = 'Paris'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

But when I make time comparison in my controller, it does work.

```
Order.where("created_at >= :start_time and meal_id = :meal", start_time: DateTime.new(Date.today.year, Date.today.month, Date.today.day - 1, 17, 0, 0), meal: @meal.ids[0])
```

The above code should display all orders that where created since yesterday 5:00pm, but the ones created from 5:00pm to 6:00pm are actually missing.

Again, the `created_at` for each meal is the right one when I look at my table in Active Admin for example, but it one hour ahead when looking at it in the console.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so after trying several things, there was actually two issues:

the first one was regarding Time, indeed. The second was @meal variable (I was using `.where` to get the right meal, but using `.find_by`made it work)

I added a `"+01:00"` a the end of my DateTime Object and it did the trick:

```
Order.where("created_at >= :start_time and meal_id = :meal", start_time: DateTime.new(Date.today.year, Date.today.month, Date.today.day - 1, 17, 0, 0, "+01:00"), meal: @meal.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `1.day.ago`, which takes into account time zone, which your code does not.

```
Order.where("created_at >= :start_time and meal_id = :meal", start_time: 1.day.ago, meal: @meal.ids[0])
```

If you want the beginning of the hour specifically, as your code implies, try `1.day.ago.beginning_of_hour`:

```
Order.where("created_at >= :start_time and meal_id = :meal", start_time: 1.day.ago.beginning_of_hour, meal: @meal.ids[0])
```

Side note: With Rails, if you find yourself doing some kind of complex date manipulation, you should see if Rails already supports it. There are tons more functions [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html)

Comment: This seems to work, but I need to get meals since yesterday from 5:00pm, I can't find the right function in the api doc to set the starting time at precisely 5pm.

Comment: Maybe something like `Time.parse("5 pm +0100") - 1.day`. Adjust time zone as needed.

Answer (score 1):

The time in database is UTC time, it's stored correctly. So you can compare with utc time to get expected result:

```
Order.where("created_at >= :start_time", start_time: 1.day.ago.beginning_of_day.utc + 16.hours)
```

so if database stores `16:00` in utc, it means 5pm in your timezone.